# Tensorflow Quantization: Speed of Op "QuantizationConv2D" and "Conv2D"

Tags: performance, tensorflow, quantization

Basically, I am testing the difference speed of Conv2D and QuantizedConv2D. I found that if I use two constant nodes as input and filter, the QuantizedConv2D is faster than Conv2D; **but** if I use a placeholder node as input, and a constant node as a filter, the QuantizedConv2D is much slower than Conv2D.

I use "tf.Session.run" method to feed data to the placeholder.

My environment is:

tensorflow-1.3(only CPU), 
compile with source code, python2.7;
(and when compiling tensorflow, I use -msse4.1)

I use python time module to test the cost time

```
a=time.time();
for i in range(NUM):
  c=sess.run([output], feed_dict={data: np_list});
b=time.time();
costime = (b-a)/NUM;
```

Can anybody share the reason?

Comment: How are you measuring the time for the op? Could you provide a repro example?

Comment: I build a 3 conv op graph, and use python time module. a=time.time(); c=sess.run([output], feed_dict={d: np_l}); b=time.time();  costime=b-a;   Did I use the wrong method? I 've been stuck with the problem for several days,  I am appreciated that if you could give me some suggestions. Thank you